# Does the data sent from sever arrives at client machine faster than recv function?

Tags: c, sockets, socket.io

Thank you in advance for reading a bit silly question.

Let me clarify the question again. 
Here's the code ( Socket programming in C) sending data to server and receive data from server.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //Send some data
    message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");
**--------MY QUESTION--------**

  //Receive a reply from the server
  if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
  {
      puts("recv failed");
  }
   puts("Reply received\n");
   puts(server_reply);



    return 0;
}
```

The Question is that after **send function** get called and before **recv function** gets called, there should be already data from server written in the socket from what i understood as a programming perspective.
 That means the time for data to be sent from server and arrive at client machine is always faster than the time taken to call the recv function.

would you be able to correct me if i miss something ?

Comment: "That means the time for data to be sent from server and arrive at client machine is always faster than the time taken to call the recv function." No it doesn't. If there is no data, `recv()` will block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two possibilities - to use blocking socket or to use non-blocking. Blocking socket waits until data is received and in case of non-blocking recv() just gets what is on socket's buffer and continues.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a "blocking" recv (which is the default).  So it waits until data is available.  It's not known how much data you will receive, so you need to be prepared to get a partial message (and probably call recv() again to get the rest).